# Why the output is printed "Not Wierd" When the input is 18?

Tags: python, if-statement

Why the output is printed "Not Wierd" When the input is 18?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input().strip())
    if(n%2==0):
        if(range(2,5)):
            print("Not Weird")
        elif(range(6,20)):
            print("Weird")
        elif(n>20):
            print("Not Weird")
    else:
        print("Weird")
```

Comment: if(range(2,5)) doesnt make any sense

Comment: I suspect that `if range(2,5):` will always turn out to be true.

Comment: Any non-empty range is truth-y, so this will *always* print `"Not Weird"` for even numbers.

Comment: What do you expect `if(range(2,5))` to do?  It isn't checking if n is in that range, if that's what you intended.

Comment: Use `if n in range(2,5)` or `if 2 <= n < 5` instead.

Comment: Also, `range`s do _not_ include their end-point. Your code makes me think you think the otherwise. e.g. if you input 20, nothing will be printed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is with your use or `range()`, which returns an iterable, which is a truthy value (if it's not empty), hence your first conditional always being true.

Update it so you are checking if your number is inside the iterable returned by `range()`

```
...
if(n in range(2,5)):
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `n in range(...)` to see if `n` is within range.